# Should beginners be advised to use dual rail power for audio circuits?

Tags: power-supply, audio, switch-mode-power-supply

A recent question has gotten me thinking as to what power supply advice should be given to audio circuit beginners.

There are 100s of matches for a "dual rail" search in this forum.  There are many "Similar Questions - single rail problem*****" coming up on the right hand site of my screen.  People regularly ask for the pros and cons and we tell them.  We're also always correcting beginner's circuits who have failed to adequately bias transistors or create effective virtual grounds. And endless corrections to circuits that can't drive the output to near zero. This confusion is multiplied by circuits with several decoupled stages.

Isn't it simpler to just recommend something like a dual rail DC-DC converter as below (arbitrary example):-

[image: dc-dc converter]

So it's £6.  Most members here should be able to afford that and it kinda pays for itself with reduced paracetamol and component count.  It runs off anything from +3.3V to +24V and can produce +/-3V to +/-24V.  They'll easily manage 100mA /rail.  They even have zero minimum load requirements these days.  A converter would solve many of the question issues posed here for transistor and op amp based circuits.  It's one component, professionally designed and manufactured hence very reliable.  Noise is not at issue at audio frequencies.

Personally this the first solution I reach for with anything op ampy. I operate on the principle of *build what you must, buy what you can*.  I'm not suggesting a treatise on the pros & cons of DC-DC converters, but rather might this be a form of beginner's best practice advice?

Comment: There are no rights and wrongs - just opinions.

Comment: This post reads as an advertisement for isolated DC/DC converters, as well as a forum/discussion format, neither of which are appropriate here.

Comment: Switchers will add noise, thus the newbie will wonder just why the signals always are creepy-crawly with trash. Have them start out with 2 lantern batteries, 6volts each.

Comment: Is this better for meta as people here seem unwilling to think much?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to disagree that dual rail is 'easier' for a newbie to Op-Amp based audio circuits.
There are plenty of single rail, rail-rail op-amps available and for many new to audio it's best to keep to ac coupled stages for simplicity. This is especially true when you mix FET/BJT single voltage rail discrete amps with op-amp stages.

If you really need to use symmetrical rails you can always introduce a virtual ground (TLE2426, $1.20) which at least keeps the introduction to a simple single input power supply voltage. This obviates any need to teach anything about dual rail power supplies.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to agree that beginners will get more out of experimenting with dual supplies, and there are [application](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/656) [notes](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/designing-single-supply-low-power-systems.html) that go into the various issues surrounding single supply designs, although those are very common in todays equipment.

Amplifiers can be difficult enough for a beginner to understand without throwing things such as (sometimes severe) input common mode limitations (just one of the issues in a single supply workld).

It is interesting to note that Maxim has released a line of [opamps](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/amplifiers/MAX44267.html) (typical part linked) that integrate a charge pump so they can be powered from a single supply rail but have bipolar characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

NO.. horses for courses.

There are benefits and drawbacks of both. The truth of the matter is, beginners need to familiarize themselves with and fully understand BOTH methods.

The art is knowing when the specific design requirements warrant the extra costs involved in adding another supply.

Comment: This isn't school and you're not their teacher.  They don't need to nothin'. My question relates to discrete implementation problems that beginners have with single rail supplies and column inches here devoted to solving those problems.  There's a reason all op amp books and courses begin with dual supplies.  It's easier and less risky. The E.SE question that sparked this thread would have been more succinctly answered by a dual rail op amp solution than a large component count increase and earth virtualisation /biasing.

Comment: @PaulUszak wow... I simply stated beginners should know exactly what you are saying.... *Should they be advised to use dual... * was your original title... The answer to that is no, they should be informed, because they "need to know", the differences. It is up to them to chose which path to take.

Comment: Also... advising someone to add a £6 part when a couple of resistors and a capacitor might be all they need is just plain wrong. And FYI the reason most textbooks start out with dual supply op-amps is because, for a few decades, that was all we could get.

Comment: And the on line tutorials?  Were they written 40 years ago too?  Perhaps Horowitz & Hill also are unaware of your new fangled single rail op amps.  And naively forcing the signal line up with a couple of resistors destroys any impedance matching and frequency response, so it's not that simple is it?  It makes it much more complicated. Complication which I'm suggesting could be easily avoided for £6.  You spent that on those ring tones you bought.  Although I guess reiterating this old mantra accumulates reputation which is the objective after all.

Comment: @PaulUszak I have no idea why you chose me to argue with. I agree double ended is better in a lot of cases, and I personally prefer it most of the time. However, that doesn't mean I would ALWAYS advise someone to use them. Rather I would explain the relative benefits and drawbacks of each and let them decide on their own. If the particular problem at hand was known I might say what I personally would do, but that's it. But that was not the question you asked.

Comment: Don't ask "opinion" questions if you are not going to like the answers.